# Git multiply accounts issues

Tags: git, macos, github, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Multiple Github accounts make me crazy. So I have two my own github accounts.

I found really useful [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574) to add multiply account on my Mac. So first off all I already have working copy on my Mac and seems now it work when I did all steps from that video tutorial.

But when I try to push my changes via Source Tree I see this:

```
Pushing to https://github.com/SuperApps/SuperApp.git
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/SuperApps/SuperApp.git/' not found
```

thought right after this message I open terminal and make:

```
git push origin new_branch
```

And I see this:

```
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 40.45 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/SuperApps/SuperApp.git
   8f89744..0b89b79  new_branch -> new_branch
```

which means that https://github.com/SuperApps/SuperApp.git exists and I can push to it but not via Source Tree.

Alos when I tried in terminal this:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
The authenticity of host 'github.com (IP ADDRESS HERE)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:kThbg6kBlpJW4l7E1IGO5lpRomTxdCARLviKw7GHSY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

And when I written yes:
Hi MySecondAccountName! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

But when I am checking commits on github the author is MyFirstAccountName.

I've checked also SourceTree settings and there is MySecondAccountName is default github account. Seems should works but it does not.

To summarise:

1. I have problem to push changes via SourceTree but not via terminal.
2. Does actually `ssh -T git@github.com` means that I should see current git authorised user. If yes why I see commits from my another git user.

So here few problems.

Comment: I don't have time for a proper answer, but I'll just say: the *author name* in a git commit is set at time time you make the commit, based on `user.name` and `user.email` in the *git* config. The ssh session *user name* is set at the time you run `ssh` (or `git push` runs `ssh` for you), which is long after that; you'll push the author name you set earlier.  Meanwhile I know nothing about using SourceTree, which is where the main problem seems to be.

Comment: @torek ok got your idea about user.email and user.name thanks